# Number of outcomes with 3 distinct numbers rolling 4 dice.

Tags: probability

Suppose you roll 4 distinct dice. I am trying to find:

a) The number of outcomes with 3 distinct numbers

b) The number of outcomes with 2 distinct numbers

I just want to check that my reasoning is correct.

For (a): There are $6$ ways to choose the number that is repeated twice and $5*4$ ways to choose the numbers that appears only once. Then the number of orderings is ${4 \choose 2}\times 2$. So the total number of outcomes is $6\times5\times4\times{4 \choose 2}\times 2$

For (b): There are ${6\choose 2}$ ways of choosing the 2 numbers that each appear twice. Now there are ${4\choose2}$ choices for the position of the first pair, and once this is chosen the position of the other pair is automatically determined. Hence ${6\choose 2} \times {4\choose 2}$ total outcomes.

Comment: I'm confused. There is no number that occurs thrice in (a).

Comment: For (b) there are two different ways to get two distinct numbers. You are only counting one of them.

Comment: Oh yes, I misread (a), I'll fix it now.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I fixed the solution for (a) is this right now?

Comment: Yes, (a) is correct, but (b) is still wrong. You need to include 1112, for example, not just 1122.

Comment: Oh yes, I'll fix this now.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews would I just add $6\times5\times{4\choose 3}$, for (b)?

Comment: Actually, I'm rethinking if $(a)$ is correct, also. I think the "$\times 2$" at the end is wrong.

Comment: But you could have 1231 and 1321, which is why I thought of including it

Comment: I'm fairly certain (a) is incorrect: $6\times5\times4\times{4 \choose 2}\times 2 = 1440 > 6^4$. I think the factor of $2$ is the error.

Comment: Basically, you've already considered the order of the two numbers that occur once when you computed $6\times 5\times 4$ You now just need to place them in $\binom{4}{2}$ ways. Another way is to write it as $6\times\binom{5}{2}\times\binom{4}{2}\times 2$ - you choose a pair, then you choose their positions, then you choose their orders.

Comment: A simple way to check your work is if $6+a_2+a_3+6\cdot 5\cdot 4\cdot 3 = 6^4$, where $a_2$ is the answer you get for (2) and $a_3$ is the answer you get for (1).

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Do you want to post an answer? If not, I'll summarize these comments in a community wiki.

Comment: For b) you have two cases to consider, 2 of each, or 3 of one number and 1 of the other.  Alternatively, with the result from a), find the ways to roll a "rainbow" (none the same 6*5*4*3) and the ways to roll a quadruple (6), and there are 6^4 outcomes for 4 dice.  And by elimination you have b).

Comment: @ThomasAndrews: I hadn't read all the comments before I posted. Pl. post your answer, I'll delete.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In [your other, similar question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1771578), you counted correctly: You selected numbers for each multiplicity without order. In that case, you had three numbers occurring twice, and you chose them in $\binom33$ ways from the $3$ numbers available. Likewise, here in (a) you need to choose the $2$ numbers that don't repeat in $\binom52=\frac{5\cdot4}2$ ways from the $5$ numbers available. Alternatively, you can choose them with order, but then you mustn't include the factor $2$ when counting orderings, since you've already chosen an order for them.

Thomas Andrews already suggested a check for your results in a comment. Like for your other question, we can also check the results using inclusion-exclusion.

For (a), we have

$$
\binom63\sum_{k=0}^3(-1)^k\binom3k(3-k)^4=20\left(3^4-3\cdot2^4+3\cdot1^4\right)=720\;,
$$

and for (b) we have

$$
\binom62\sum_{k=0}^2(-1)^k\binom2k(2-k)^4=15\left(2^4-2\cdot1^4\right)=210\;.
$$

This agrees with the counts you get if you remove the factor $2$ in (a) and include the missing case in (b) pointed out by Thomas Andrews in a comment.

Answer (score 1):

You could  adopt a system of choosing numbers "of a kind" as for poker and permute them:

**(a)**

$2-1-1:$ of a kind: $\binom61\binom52 \times \frac{4!}{2!}$

**(b)**

$3-1\;$ of a kind: $\binom61\binom51 \times \frac{4!}{3!}$

$2-2\;$ of a kind: $\binom62 \times \frac{4!}{2!2!}$